# react-router-dom gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following implementation of "react-router-dom", but I am not able to get it working. can someone guide me what's the underlying issue.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Main from "../components/Main";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


  const App = () => (

   <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Main} />
            <Match pattern="/home" component={Home} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

export default App;
```

**Index.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Home from "./components/Home";

import Page from './components/Page';
import App from "./config/App";


ReactDOM.render( 
   <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**I get the following error :**[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [docs of React Router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

`Match` and `Miss` are from previous versions of react-router-v4.alpha

With the current stable release of v4. You should use `Route` instead of `Match`. `Miss` is not there anymore.

I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use Route instead of match.
Second, imports are case sensitive.
Third, [match](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md) as per the doc you will get match object as prop.